# C# app can't find Dll when compiled with /MDd flag

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, loading

I have a C# application which links to a few c# DLLs which in turn use bindings to call c++ functions in other Dlls.

This all works fine if I compile the c++ Dlls with /MTd but when I use /MDd I get an XMLParseException in my C# app complaining that it can't find any Dlls(it fails to find the first of my Dlls that I use). My best guess is that using this other switch causes it to change the path where it looks for its Dlls, causing it to fail. I used DependencyWalker to have a closer look and the two Dlls it actually fails to find are 'IESHIMS.DLL' and 'WER.DLL'. I can't see my c# Dlls anywhere in the tree in DependecyWalker however. Anyone have any ideas what might be wrong here?

Also, using the non-debug equivalents (/MD and /MT) make no difference. Regardless, I can't use /MT as it causes another bug.

EDIT: I've narrowed the problem down somewhat. When compiled and linked using the VS2010 command prompt, my app works fine, with the VS2008 command prompt it still fails to find the Dll. Does anyone know any differences between these two version of VS which could cause the behaviour I described above?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling all the modules against the same run-time libraries?  From:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(VS.80).aspx

"All modules passed to a given invocation of the linker must have been compiled with the same run-time library compiler option (/MD, /MT, /LD)."

Comment: Yeah all my c++ Dlls are compiled with this option.